# Questions on structuring T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I'm learning T-SQL and trying to get my head around how to approach it/best practices.  Working through some examples, there are three questions I have:

1)  Coming from Python, is there a generally agreed upon style guide (something like PEP 8) or approach for laying out T-SQL or is it more like JavaScript where anything goes?

2)  When creating stored procedures and functions I see some authors always use a main BEGIN/END block and others don't.  At first I thought you need BEGIN/END if you have more than one statement.  However, this doesn't seem to be true because I have seen lengthy stored procedures with no main BEGIN/END.  Any thoughts on this?

3)  Within stored procedures, some authors seem to like to enclose parts of their code in BEGIN/END blocks.  I can't see why you'd do this and wonder if I'm missing something.  For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <NAME> (
  <Parameter List...>
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Setup:
    -- Declare/initialize variables...

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- Validity check 1:
        IF @Param1 ...
        BEGIN
            -- Do stuff...
        END

        -- Validity check 2
        IF @Param2 ...
        BEGIN
            -- Do stuff...
        END
        -- Update - added BEGIN/END after if blocks for clarity

        -- Why wrap these statements in a BEGIN/END Block???
        BEGIN
            --Add the entry
            INSERT dbo.JournalClientFamilyChanges (
                    HouseholdMembersID,
                    PreviousClientsID,
                    NewClientsID,
                    ActionTaken,
                    Notes,
                    ModifiedBy,
                    ModifiedDate
                )
            VALUES (
                    @HouseholdMembersID,
                    @PreviousClientsID,
                    @NewClientsID,
                    @ActionTaken,
                    @Notes,
                    @ModifiedBy,
                    SYSDATETIME()
                )

            SET @success =1;
            SET @ErrorStatus ='';
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Error handling...
    END CATCH
END
```

Any thoughts appreciated,

--Jim

Comment: `BEGIN`...`END` represents a code block in T-SQL, much like `{...}` in c# or indentation in python.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's what I thought.  However, when I look at how people use BEGIN...END in T-SQL, it doesn't match up with code blocks in non-SQL languages.  In C++ or Python, there are very specific reasons to use a block - if you need more than one statement, you need it, otherwise you don't.  However, much of the T-SQL code I'm reading doesn't follow these rules.  So my question is, why?

Comment: In T-SQL you are allowed to add code blocks even if you don't need them. I once had a project that used very long stored procedures, and I've divided them the parts using `begin...end` just to be able to collapse them in SSMS to see only the relevant code. TSQL also contains a lot of optional syntax - for example - you can write `insert into table (col1, col2) values (val1, val2)` but you can also write `insert table values (val1, val2)` - and if the table only contains the two columns both will work the same (though it's best practice to always include the column names).

Comment: Ahhh - being able to collapse the code in SSMS makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question at your own example

```
    IF @Param1 ...

    -- Validity check 2
    IF @Param2 ...

    -- Why wrap these statements in a BEGIN/END Block???
    BEGIN
        --Add the entry
        INSERT dbo.JournalClientFamilyChanges (
                HouseholdMembersID,
                ...
            )
        VALUES (
                @HouseholdMembersID,
                @PreviousClientsID,
                ... 
            )

        SET @success =1;
        SET @ErrorStatus ='';
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END
```

There is an `IF` which will call the code below just under certain circumstances. Without the `BEGIN ... END` this will be valid for the very next statement only. Using `BEGIN ... END` will see the whole code block covered by the `IF` condition (the lines with `SET` and `COMMIT`).

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @SomeInt INT=0;

IF @SomeInt=1
PRINT 'Example 1: hello, this is the first line';
PRINT 'Example 1: hello, the next line';

IF @SomeInt=1
BEGIN
PRINT 'Example 2: hello, this is the first line';
PRINT 'Example 2: hello, the next line';
END
```

For better readability one would use indents. But this is not relevant for the engine. There are some languages using indents as block marker though, others use paranthesis or any kind of brackets. T-SQL uses `BEGIN ... END`. Sometimes people use this in larger procedures just to allow collapsing (like the `#region` in C#)

```
IF @SomeInt=1
    PRINT 'Example 1: hello, this is the first line';

PRINT 'Example 1: hello, the next line';

IF @SomeInt=1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Example 2: hello, this is the first line';
    PRINT 'Example 2: hello, the next line';
END
```

### update

Just to reflect the comments below: The OP changed the initial question in a way, that the `BEGIN ... END` is no longer connected to the `IF`. So the question shoudl be: *Why would one use `BEGIN ... END` without any functional reason?*.

The answer for this is

- To mark some lines of code as a "block"
- ... thus emphasising the functional unit
- Collapsing is a nice side-effect

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I apologize my example was unclear.  I am familar with how IF works if you use/don't use a block.  I updated my example to show this is not what I'm looking for.  However, it might be as simple as using BEGIN...END to allow collapsing the code in an editor as you suggest.

Comment: @JamesS. Okay, that edited sample is something else now... :-) No problem... Using `BEGIN ... END` is a nice way to mark some lines of code as a "block", thus emphasising the functional unit... Collapsing is a nice side-effect...

Comment: @JamesS. Your changes somehow invalidated my answer... You might to read my update...